# XSD XML - validation error while using restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two valid XSD files (a.xsd and b.xsd). I try to validated a XML file (example.xml) against the Schema and get an error.

Can anybody explain to me, why I get a validation error?

THX

---

a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://namespace/a" xmlns:a="http://namespace/a" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="E1" type="xs:token" form="unqualified"/>
      <xs:element name="E2" type="xs:token" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

b.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://namespace/b" xmlns:b="http://namespace/b" xmlns:a="http://namespace/a" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import namespace="http://namespace/a" schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="START" type="b:B"/>
  <xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="a:A">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="E1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                <xs:enumeration value="value1">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <codeName>value1</codeName>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="value2">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <codeName>value2</codeName>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
                <xs:enumeration value="value3">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <codeName>value3</codeName>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:enumeration>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:START xmlns="http://namespace/a" xmlns:b="http://namespace/b" xsi:schemaLocation="http://namespace/b C:\problem\b.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <E1>value1</E1>
</b:START>
```

Comment: I also want to generate Java classes via JAXB (unmarshal & marshal) with this XSDs. If the take the solution from Petru with the empty namespace, the content from E1 is not be mapped into the Java class, because the definition from a.xsd is, that E1 belongs to namespace http://namespace/a ...

Answer (score 2):

It is the declaration of `xmlns="http://namespace/a"` in your sample XML which throws your XML off... And it is because your a.xsd uses the `form="unqualified"/` attribute to define E1 and E2.

The effect of this attribute is that it denies a namespace to your element, which is to say these elements must have no namespace - they're not qualified.

To fix your XML you have two options, based on your sample:

Remove the `xmlns="http://namespace/a"` from your root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:START xmlns:b="http://namespace/b" xsi:schemaLocation="http://namespace/b b.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <E1>value1</E1>
</b:START>
```

OR, add xmlns="" to your E1 element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<START xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://namespace/a" xmlns="http://namespace/b">
    <E1 xmlns="">value1</E1>
</START>
```

There might be other variants, but in the end, the above are essential to understand how to eventually override at the element level a namespace (scoping, basically).

Comment: Ok, understood ... next question: What should be changed in the XSDs to use them for JAXB (marshal / unmarshal)? Because in the generated classes the E1 element is in namespace ''http://namespace/a'', what goes to the validation error.

Comment: @user3083431, you should create a new question and tag it 'jaxb' (in addition to whatever other tags you may want). Don't forget to add details about your JAXB setup, such as versioning information, relevant snippets of the generated code, etc.